# assign IP to tinyproxy on OpenWrt

Tags: iptables, openvpn, openwrt

I have installed `tinyproxy` on OpenWrt and now I want to make rules for iptables that match traffic from tinyproxy. I want to mark this traffic with set-mark and route it to different routing table. My router has IP 192.168.0.1 but how to set up tinyproxy's IP to distinguish it from router's IP?